# making a link toggle between SlideDown and SlideUp (scriptaculous)

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous, slideup, slidedown

The scriptaculous wiki has a demo (http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/effect-slidedown) that shows the SlideDown effect in use. However I need to have the same link to slide down if a certain DIV is hidden and SlideUp if that DIV is showing.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Effect.toggle](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/wikis/effect-toggle).

```
Effect.toggle('element_id', 'slide');
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function, call the function instead.

```
function slideMe(myDiv) {

    if(Element.visible(myDiv)) {
    //slide up

    }

    else {

    //slide down

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly valid way of doing this. Why vote it down? Voting down is for WRONG answers.

Comment: Yes this is a valid answer. Thank you Diodeus i'm using your way. +1